# Is there any floating number support in Cairo 1?

Tags: starknet, cairo-lang

I know, it's been a few day that Cairo 1 was released and I had a question about floating number since some months.

I know that, for Solidity, dealing with is even not a thing but as Cairo is about computation scaling, is going to support floating point number? If yes, where is it defined?

Thank you.